# The object of class oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ from mapping could not be converted to class java.util.Date

Tags: oracle, jpa, timestamp, eclipselink, websphere-liberty

I am facing an issue in eclipselink with TIMESTAMPTZ. There is a column in table which have timestamp and timezone. When I run my program I am getting exception.

> *I have tried everything already on stackOverflow with similar issues and even on the below link.*

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/443917/

---

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_Schema.MyTable MT WHERE MT.START_DT = (SELECT MAX(START_DT) FROM MY_Schema.MyTable)",MyTable.class);
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable", schema = "MY_Schema")
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MyTableId id;
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class MyTableId implements Serializable {

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "END_DT")
  private Calendar endTime;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "START_DT")
  private Calendar startTime;
```

---

Error message:

```
5943 [Default Executor-thread-32] ERROR com....MyClass  - 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-3002]
(Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.8.WAS-v20181218-0accd7f):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException Exception
Description: The object [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ@d1f0d927], of class
[class oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ], from mapping
[org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[startTime--Y_Schema.MyTable.START_DT]]
with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(com.....MyTableId -->
[DatabaseTable(MY_Schema.MyTable)])], could not be converted to [class
java.util.Date].    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:551)
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrade to 2.7.2 or newer eclipselink? If I remember correctly, the TIMESTAMPZ convertion was broken between 2.6.6 and 2.7.1

Comment: Maybe it is this issue https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522408

Comment: @Bedla I tried after upgrading eclipseLink version to 2.7.2 but same result :(

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971745/eclipselink-not-converting-oracle-sql-timestamptz

Comment: Hi @user3092515 did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: Hi @Irtaza I could not find a direct solution, so I created my own converter

Comment: thanks @user3092515, could you share the converter? would be really helpful

Comment: @Irtaza
Here is the link to how to implement an attribute converter in JPA
https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-attributeconverter/