# Eclipselink not converting oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ

Tags: eclipselink

I am getting an error when I am fetching value from DB using Eclipselink as persistence provider. *It is not converting oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ to java.sql.Timestamp or to java.util.Date*.

---

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_Schema.MyTable MT WHERE MT.START_DT = (SELECT MAX(START_DT) FROM MY_Schema.MyTable)",MyTable.class);
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable", schema = "MY_Schema")
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MyTableId id;
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class MyTableId implements Serializable {

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "END_DT")
  private Calendar endTime;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "START_DT")
  private Calendar startTime;
```

---

***Exception***

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services- 2.6.8.WAS-v20181218-0accd7f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException ExceptionDescription: The object [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ@6156ebf7], of class[class oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ], could not be converted to [class java.sql.Timestamp].     at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(ConversionException.java:78) at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToTimest mp(ConversionManager.java:751) at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObject(ConversionManager.java:112)

---

---

***Things I found***

> While debugging I found that in eclipselink ConversionManager class
>   there is no handling for oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ. It is directly throwing exception in this method.

---

---

```
/**
     * INTERNAL:
     * Build a valid instance of java.sql.Timestamp from the given source object.
     * @param sourceObject    Valid object of class java.sql.Timestamp, String, java.util.Date, or Long
     */
    protected java.sql.Timestamp convertObjectToTimestamp(Object sourceObject) throws ConversionException {
        java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = null;

        if (sourceObject instanceof java.sql.Timestamp) {
            return (java.sql.Timestamp)sourceObject;// Helper timestamp is not caught on class check.
        }

        if (sourceObject instanceof String) {
            timestamp = Helper.timestampFromString((String)sourceObject);
        } else if (sourceObject instanceof java.util.Date) {// This handles all date and subclasses, sql.Date, sql.Time conversions.
            timestamp = Helper.timestampFromDate((java.util.Date)sourceObject);
        } else if (sourceObject instanceof Calendar) {
            return Helper.timestampFromCalendar((Calendar)sourceObject);
        } else if (sourceObject instanceof Long) {
            timestamp = Helper.timestampFromLong((Long)sourceObject);
        } else {
            throw ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(sourceObject, ClassConstants.TIMESTAMP);
        }
        return timestamp;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ handling is DB specific and done by subclasses of the Oracle9Platform. Make sure you have specified the correct target-database platform class that matches your database using the ['target-database'](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm) persistence property